# Ubuntu on Intel Compute Stick doesn't load

Tags: 16.04

Trying to install Ubuntu on Intel Compute Stick and it is stuck on login screen. Any ideas why it doesn't load?

Installing from a USB, Ubuntu 16.04, on Intel Compute Stick with Intel atom with Intel graphics. It is supposed to allow me to test before installing or install but it stucks on login screen with Ubuntu logo and dots underneath.

Comment: Please add more details: how did you install, what exactly did you install, what hardware is it running on (especially graphics), what exactly do you mean by "stuck on login screen" - describe what you see, what you expected to happen and what exactly happens instead, please. You have to give us some information to work with, we can't guess what's happening just from "it doesn't work".

Comment: Installing from a USB, Ubuntu 16.04, on Intel Compute Stick with Intel atom with Intel graphics. It is supposed to allow me to test before installing or install but it stucks on login screen with Ubuntu logo and dots underneath...

Comment: That orange screen with the Ubuntu logo and blinking dots is not the login screen but the boot screen ("Plymouth"). Can you press ESC and check if there are any messages?

Comment: Which Intel Compute Stick?  The one with only  1G of memory needs Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: If you have the STK1A32SC stick, you can run Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.1 using @kenorb's answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/1035774/99054)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

- [Install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on the 2GB Intel Compute Stick](https://liliputing.com/2015/07/install-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-the-2gb-intel-compute-stick.html)

Basically make sure you're using ISO which was respun using `isorespin.sh` (check [GitHub mirror repo](https://github.com/kenorb-contrib/isorespin)) as per [these instructions](https://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/06/customizing-ubuntu-isos-documentation.html), or download and use [Ian Morrison’s ISO disk image](http://linuxminipcs.com/isos). Flash OS image onto USB using `dd`, then try booting again.